# Widgets vs. Extensions in Magento

Tags: magento

Magento has upgraded its version to 1.4 and in introducing the version 1.4 the new handy features of widgets are introduced. Extensions are also supported by version 1.4+. I want to know if widgets are more handy (I think they are) than extensions or not and how many users have switched to widgets. Which one is more better widgets or extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Widgets and extensions are not mutually exclusive. A widget is a nice way to let users who are not so technical add blocks of functionality to their pages, providing a boost over the blocks that users had to interact with before.

That said, a widget is created as part of an extension, and is generally limited to visual changes to the page. A Widget cannot be used, for example, to trigger a cron script or change core functionality in Magento. For that reason, widgets are not the end-all solution.

In the future, expect to see widgets used in all sorts of places to build extra functionality into the frontend of a site. Also expect to see other extensions running strong without them, editing functionality on the site.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: i have developed some widgets for magento currently i thinks that till now the widgets have not gained as much popularity as extensions. Am i correct.

Comment: Extensions have been around for a long time. Widgets were added to CE in 1.4, just a little while ago. This alone would account for the difference. You are correct, though, that widgets are still up and coming.